# Show DialogFragment when Spinner is clicked

Tags: java, android, onclick, spinner, dialogfragment

I want to show a DialogFragment with a DatePicker when the Spinner is clicked.
I am not asking for the DialogFragment part, just for how to know when the Spinner is clicked, since you can't implement an onClick handler, only setOnItemSelectedListener (otherwise it gives you an error).
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cant use a spinner to show a dialog, spinners show a dropdown list.

you can however make something look like a spinner that you can register an onCLick listener by changing its style

for example use a textview and set the style to

```
style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"
```

then you can set an onClick listener on the textview and show the dialog

Comment: It requires API 11, but it's muuch easier :P Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use a spinner for an onClick handler if you don't intend to populate it with items? I would just use a button.

Comment: I would, to. But my "teacher" asked me to do it with a spinner... After the date is picked, I would show it in the spinner.

Comment: Okay.... That's an odd request as I'm sure no one would ever do that. My guess is that he wants something like the Google Calendar App ( http://postimg.org/image/s8gjv04jb/ ). But my guess is that they used a stylized button to look like a spinner, or a textview perhaps.

Comment: which is exactly what my answer does